# Does deprecated methods are executed by the lastest API?

Tags: android, webkit

I work on a project which works on the API 19 at least.

I'm using a `WebView` however, in order to handle errors, I use on the `WebViewClient` the method `OnReceivedError` and as you can see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedError%28android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest,%20android.webkit.WebResourceError%29), 
there are two method, one deprecated and an other which only works on the API 23.

I made some researchs and I saw to solve the problem this code

```
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            onReceivedError(view, error.getErrorCode(), error.getDescription().toString(), request.getUrl().toString());
        }
```

However, I wondered if on a device which works on the API 23, `onReceivedError` would be execute twice. If this is the case, what can I do to execute the code once, whatever the API (min 19, max 23) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the lower level function, check the build version and return immediately if the version is M or later.

Comment: Wow, thanks for this fast answer, so, as you said, a device who works on a API level 23 will execute both function, so the return will cancel the first one, am I right ?

Comment: Right.  That way only one will execute on any device